# Not sure why getting this failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api

Not sure why getting this failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in Youtube API

If I try public api - it works

but if I use server ip and referer domain. its showing error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=viewCount&maxResults=5&q=Sydney&key={mykey}): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in filepath.php on line 8
```

Can anyone help me, how can I resolve this issue

Comment: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=5&order=viewCount&q=Sydney&key={YOUR_API_KEY}` that is the correct request. I just did a test with my API key and it works just fine...